# Getting error when trying to setup Amazon S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to transfer an S3 bucket to another since a developer is leaving our team.  I created another AWS account with S3.  I'm following these steps:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-s3/

The Bucket policy in for source AWS account works fine, but when I try the destination policy:

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*",
               "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket/*"
          ]
     }
}
```

And update only the sourcebucket and dest bucket items above with my account details, I get the error:
**Statement is missing required element - Statement "NO_ID-0" is missing "Principal" element**

Comment: Wondering why you have chosen to transfer the S3 bucket to a new AWS account. Are you giving each developer a unique AWS account? That's not a good, sustainable model.

Comment: It was setup incorrectly, a developer created with his personal Amazon account and how is leaving the company.  So we created a company account and need everything transferred there.

Comment: OK, sounds good. As Michael indicated, the set of instructions provides two polices. The first is a bucket policy (apply it to the source bucket); the second is an IAM user policy (apply it to the IAM user in the target account who is going to be doing the copy).

Answer (score 6):

The destination policy in the article you cited is not a *bucket* policy.  It's an IAM user or group policy.

Note the comment:

```
#User or group policy in the destination AWS account
```

This policy attaches to an IAM user or group in the IAM (as opposed to S3) console.

The source policy actually is a bucket policy, which is why it works as expected.